# BigVideo JS not showing poster

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am using bigvideo js and would like to display a poster when the video is complete. Not sure what im doing wrong here any help would be great.

```
    vid.show('vid/video.mp4');
    vid.getPlayer().on("ended", function(){
        vid.getPlayer().posterImage.show('/posters/poster.jpg');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, what you're doing however is grabbing the videojs method and trying to show the poster but in the bigvideo source there's a method named showPoster(source) (line 239 in BigVideo.js-1.1.5-1) which stops the video, hides the video element and shows the poster.

In my case I wanted a pre-loading image and ended up with a rather modified version of what this guy made:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/19/fullscreen-video-slideshow-with-bigvideo-js/